# Calculating the definite integral of a function

Tags: definite-integrals

I have a problem with understanding the following integral:

$\int_{x_1}^{x_1+\Delta x}[{u(x_1+\Delta x,t)-u(x_1,t)]dx}=[u(x_1+\Delta x,t)-u(x_1,t)]\Delta x$.

I don't understand why we can find the integral of u by just multiplying it by the difference in the upper and lower bound. Why don't we do anything with the u-expression.

Comment: Because the integration variable isn't $x_1$ but $x$, both your $u$ functions have $x_1$ as argument.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What would have happened if the u functions did not have $x_1$ as argument, but only $x$?

Comment: Do you have specific hypothesis on the $u$ function?

Comment: I mean... assuming the $u$ is at least continuous you have that there's $c \in [x_1,x_1 + \Delta_x]$ such that $I = \frac{u(z + \Delta_x,t) - u(z,t)}{\Delta_x}$, if you further assume the partial derivative respect to $x$ exists and that $\Delta_x \rightarrow 0$ you have that $I = \left. \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right|_{x=z} $

Comment: I mean if we had $\int_{x_1}^{x_1+\Delta x}[{u(x,t_1+\Delta t)-u(x,t)]dx}$ instead

Comment: I don't think you can calculate the integral in that case... but you could infer some property, like the one in my previous comment. (By the way... $c$ and $z$ are the same thing... sorry for that)

Comment: Discard my previous comment... but what i meant to say is that you can apply the mean value theorem to your integral. That's all i can say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x_1$ is a constant independent of $x$. Thus

$\int_{x_1}^{x_1+\Delta x}[u(x_1+\Delta x,t)-u(x_1,t)]dx=[u(x_1+\Delta x,t)-u(x_1,t)]\int_{x_1}^{x_1+\Delta x}dx$

and obviously $\int_{x_1}^{x_1+\Delta x}dx=\Delta x$

Answer (score 2):

Both $u(x_1+\Delta x,t)$ and $u(x_1,t)$ are constant in $[x_1,x_1+\Delta x]$. Note that you are integrating on the variable $x$, which does not appear in any of the functions. Thus

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_1+\Delta x}[{u(x_1+\Delta x,t)-u(x_1,t)]dx}=[u(x_1+\Delta x,t)-u(x_1,t)]\int_{x_1}^{x_1+\Delta x} dx=[u(x_1+\Delta x,t)-u(x_1,t)]\Delta x,$$

$\Delta x$ being the length of the interval.